Translating command "Be of highest value!" to French for jewelry engraving
What is the most accurate translation in French for the command "Be of highest value!"? The meaning of the phrase is to behave as someone who brings out the best in others. As in, be the highest value person (for others, or to others)... Imagine it as advice a wise elder is imparting to a young man.
This translation will be engraved on a piece of jewelry.
I am somewhat confused on how to best express this translation. Thus, I have come to the community for help. Thanks in advance.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The following sentences are not exact equivalent, but are idiomatic :


Sois la meilleure version de toi-même.
Donne le meilleur de toi-même.


